# Sudden surge in network usage by unknown processes

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-4, mobile-network, data-monitoring, firewall

Phone Details:

```
Model: Nexus 4 (mako)
Current ROM: Paranoid Android 4.3-BETA2
Xposed Present? Yes
```

I flashed the new `Paranoid Android 4.4- BETA1` today and noticed my phone downloading something. I had not initiated any downloads, so I assumed it was just some app syncing. After about 3 minutes, it had downloaded around 50MB which seemed fishy. So, I assumed that the `Paranoid Android` build was buggy and switched back to 4.3-BETA2. However, the problem seemed to be infectious.

On the 4.4-BETA1 build it was just one port which was used for downloading and it was the port for `com.google.uid.shared:10050`.

However, now there are several ports which are downloading. They're all apparently in the foreground. Any idea how I can find which app introduced them and remove them? As a temporary solution I'm using a firewall.

**Screenshots**

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Did you do a clean flash of PA 4.4 B1 or did you install it over the top of your previous ROM?

Comment: To be more clear: Did your "new flash" include a wipe of Dalvik, Cache, and Data?

Comment: @1990clb - Since it was just an update, I flashed it over the previous ROM. The return to the 4.3-BETA2 was also by flashing. I didn't restore a backup.

Comment: @Izzy - Yes, it included a wipe of Dalvik and Cache for the switch from PA4.3-B2 to PA4.4-B1, up on return it included was a factory reset followed by flashing of PA4.3-B2 and Dalvik, Cache wipe.

Comment: Okay, first thing I would try is re-flash but with a factory reset. They did advise this on the Google+ page but it was hard to spot!
https://plus.google.com/107979589566958860409/posts/GqHdB661aEr

Comment: @1990clb - As you can see from my reply to izzy, I did do that while switching back to my original ROM.